# sbt javacOptions source, target v/s scalacOptions target

Tags: java, scala, sbt, version

I have jdk 17 installed on my machine.
And I want to release my sbt projects compatible with jdk 8.
Kindly suggest, which one of the below options are required or both of the options are required in build.sbt :-

```
    javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-release", "8", "-target:8")
```

sbt version in build.properties is 1.5.5

Thanks

Comment: the line with `javacOptions` looks good to me, I would say, You need only this.

Answer (score 1):

`scalac` is responsible for creating JVM targeted artifacts, and since newer versions of `scalac` deprecated `-target` and `-release` flags the correct `scalacOptions` flag is `-java-output-version`. So it becomes:

```scala
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-java-output-version", "8")
```

For your kind information `javacOptions` is used to instruct `javac` to compile sources within `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` and hence it's irrelevant to your question.